# How frequently are data dumps going to be released?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

How frequently are data dumps going to be released?  Is there a policy forming?  How about some sort of feed or differential dump?  I guess a suitable delay might be in order.

I'd like to automate some of the statistics I do, and some questions can only be answered by looking at changes in two snapshots or with a differential system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is cleverly hidden in plain sight!!

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/

> Our plan is to create a new data dump every month, reflecting all data in the system up to that month. We will seed the latest and greatest dump (at a low bitrate) as long as we can, ideally permanently.